# Booking system Question

Tags: bookings

I have a request for a Clinical Rotation Booking Type system.
Schools/Colleges need to be able to book/reserve Floors in Hospitals.  I've researched and 'tried' to use most of the modules mentioned in the [Comparison of Booking System modules](https://groups.drupal.org/node/137544).

**Example**:

Each hospital can obviously have a lot of floors:

- [Hospital A]

  - [2W] //2nd floor West
  - [NICU] //Neo nate Intensive Care Unit
  - [2E]
  - [5E]
  - etc.
- [Hospital B]

  - [2E]
  - [2W]
  - [3W]
  - etc.
- [School A]
- [School B]

A use case would be:

- School A needs to book Hospital A 2E Floor for 1.5 months
- School B tried to book Hospital A 2E but it was already taken by School A.
- School B books Hospital A 2W instead.

Each School would have it's own login and would select from a list of Hospitals.

A calendar would show for that Hospital with available time slots.

Any guidance or advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Your question needs some editing to be answerable. Perhaps you could start by telling us what flaws you found in the modules you tried that made them unsuitable for your use case.

Comment: The major flaw with all the modules I've tested (Merci, Booking Time Slots and others) is it does ok if it's one hospital to many rooms.  But I need the ability to have many hospitals with many rooms.  Schools/colleges would have the ability to book time on specific floors of the hospital.  Clinical Rotations are based on what they're learning at the time.  I reached out to several of the module developers with the use cases, but they haven't responded.  I hope this helps.  Thanks again.

Comment: I think you should edit the question to include that. It should help resolve Molot's issue that the question is too broad. I think your easy fix is to adjust your data model. From a reservation standpoint, it doesn't sound like the hospital matters - isn't that just to make it easy to see which rooms are at a hospital? I would have separate content types for the hospital and the room and use an entity reference from one to the other to help with display. But the actual reservation is one school to one hospital at one time slot, yes?